# Prisma vulnerable dependency not shown in maven dependency:tree

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jackson, prisma

Prisma scan of a spring boot application shows a vulnerability in jackson-dataformat-cbor version 2.11.0.  But this version of cbor doesn't exist in the application.

I verified this by doing `mvn dependency:tree` and `mvn dependency:list`.  But only 2.13.0-rc1 version of jackson-dataformat-cbor exists, not the 2.11.0.

Do anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the vulnerability was in the base image itself.  Not in the spring boot app.  Thanks.